# How to compile a .sln file that contains errors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

I am making a modified version of Smart Steam Emu and it does contain some errors. I don't have the time and knowledge to fix some of these errors and there are tons. These errors (from what I know) also exist in the stable build.
I need to test something and I was wondering to compile the project if it contains errors. Thanks!

IDE: Visual Studio 2013
OS: Windows 10 Creators Update

Comment: *Errors* prevent anything from working and must be fixed. *Warnings* and *Hints* can sometimes be suppressed or ignored, but *errors* cannot. There can't be *errors* in the stable build, or it would't build. Fix the errors.

Comment: @KenWhite Ok thanks for the quick reply. I did not know that it was impossible to skip build errors. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ken said, you cannot compile the solution without resolving all the errors.

That said, there are a couple of ways if you just want to test a particular project, but the **errors must be in the project that’s not referenced by the project you want to test.**

First you need to **Set the Project you want to test as Startup project**

**Method 1:** Remove the erroneous project from solution. Run the project you want to test.

**Method 2:** Run the solution. Select “Yes” when VS prompts you with question that you want to continue to run with errors.

Hope this is helpful!